# How to get lat long for indian cities in R?

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geocoding

I am trying to get lat long for Indian cities through `ggmap` package. Below is the code I have tried but it results in an error.

I created a vector with sample cities

```
library(ggmap)
mycities1<- c("Hyderabad","Chennai","Bangalore","Cochin","ARNHEM","London")
str(mycities1)
geocode(mycities1[1])
```

This is throwing out NA values though my city names are class of character.

> Warning message: geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location
>   = "Hyderabad

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: that's not the leaflet package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the `source` argument to **dsk**.

```
geocode(as.character(mycities1[1]), source = "dsk")
```

This is due to recent google-API changes.

There is also a [current github-issue](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/213) (or several actually) which adresses that problem.

> geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "XXX" --> you
>   have not registered a correct and billing-enabled Google Maps API key
>   using register_google() (ggmap v2.7,903). Enabling billing is a
>   specific step after (!) adding your credit card information.

Comment: that worked.. is there any limitations by using source = dsk?. coukd you give more info regarding this?

Comment: I dont think there are any limitations, as it is fully based on open source software and I couldnt find any daily request limitations in their [docs](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#googlestylegeocoder)